# Why is Microsoft.Extensions documented under ASP.NET

Tags: .net

Just wondering why Microsoft.Extensions library e.g. Configuration, Logging, Dependency Injection are documented under ASP.NET Core? They also can be used for other types of application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Probably because most people use .NET for ASP.NET projects. The only other viable target right now is Console.

Comment: I added a [suggestion in UserVoice](https://msdocs.uservoice.com/forums/364242-site-feedback/suggestions/32003962-in-the-api-browser-microsofteextensions-should-be).

Comment: The open source .NETCore project was spearheaded by the ASP.NET team.  They were the ones to get it started and first to have a practical usage for it.  And took care of a lot of the plumbing.  They underlying reason is pretty visible from [this graph](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=asp.net%2Cnode.js).

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.Extensions.* packages are documented under ASP.NET Core for a couple of reasons:

- They ship as part of the ASP.NET Core shared framework (which ships as part of .NET Core)
- They were primarily developed by the ASP.NET team and are most commonly used today with ASP.NET Core

That said, you are correct that the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages can be used outside of ASP.NET Core. These packages target .NET Standard and can be used wherever the corresponding version of .NET Standard is supported (ex. .NET Core, .NET Framework, Xamarin, UWP). That's why these packages don't have "AspNetCore" in their IDs.